# SQL concatenate - INSERT MANY VALUES TO ONE ROW

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm currently trying to add 3 rows in to 1 row so that the information is separated by a ','like using a concatenation. However, I'm new to this and any help will be useful. Below is my current code and what I have tried.

This code below does not work:

```
insert into GENRES (GENRES) 
select VALUES GENRE1,GENRE2,GENRE3 
from TITLES;
```

I have also tried this code below, which inserted the rows but not in the format I want:

```
insert into GENRES (GENRES) 
SELECT GENRE1 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE2 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE3 FROM titles;
```

Which displayed:

```
  GENRES
1 ACTION
2 ADVENTURE
3 ROMANCE
```

I would need it to display in this format below for example:

```
  GENRES 
1 Action, Adventure, Romance
```

Comment: Probably having one row per genre in the GENRES table is a good design. How you choose to display them is another matter. You could look at the [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) function, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation it is.

```
insert into genres (genres)
select genre1 ||', '|| genre2 ||', '|| genre3
from titles
```